# Creating algorithm matching elements on cartesian coordinate system with specific conditions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, cartesian-coordinates

1. We have `n` elements of type `X`, and `n` elements of type `Y`.
2. Both types are just points on cartesian system.
3. No more than 2 of elements (no matter what type) are collinear.

Find algorithm with complexity `O(n^2*logn)` matching every single element of type `X` with exactly one element of type `Y` (1-1) so that none of resulting segments is crossed with other.

Obviously there are more solutions than only one good - I need any of them.

Possible solution:

[image]

My algorithm (draft):

1. (Some sorting needed?)
2. Get First element of any type with minimal `x` coordinate (and with greater `y` coordinate if 2 such elements exist)
3. For every element of opposite type (iterating from max `x` and then min `y` coordinates:

   4. Check if number of elements of type `X` is the same as number of elements of type `Y` above and below resulting line (which line contains resulting segment).

      5. If yes (could be `|X|=|Y|=0`), then recursively do the same for set of points that lays above line, and then for set of points that lays below line.

         6. STOP if both above/below sets are empty
      6. If no, check another element

There will be always a matching pair in above algorithm. But I don't think this algorithm is matching complexity condition, and it is truly correct? Or maybe there is a better one?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: A wholly different idea would be to: (1) build a random matching without checking crossings, (2) for each crossing A-B and C-D, replace it with A-D and B-C. Since (2) reduces the total length of the edges in the matching, this will stop eventually. Doing step (2) in random order may even have a nice complexity, but the proof will require some tedium.

Comment: It could be a good solution, but as you mentioned I need complexity proof and in your case it could be quite difficult.

Comment: I believe that your proposed algorithm is O(N^3).  Step 3 is O(N).  For each of those, step 4 is O(N).  Your recursion is ideally O(log2(N)), but is O(N) in the worst case.  The product of those ...

Comment: From what I remember of my graph theory and topology, the method @Gassa proposes is, indeed O(N^2), although it's not trivial to prove that the number of un-crossings obeys this limit.  Proving termination and correctness is as Gassa describes.

Comment: So maybe some preprocessing in my algoithm may reduce recursion to O(logn) in worst case? Or maybe saying "set of elements above/below" points doesn't require checking every element of that set, but checking for super cool condition?